# app.manifest xml tags marked as erroneous when copy pasted

Tags: c#, rider

I am using Rider as a IDE for creating C# projects. Unfortunately, it does not come with an option to create an `app.manifest` file. For that, I jump to Visual Studio and than copy it to Rider.

When I do that, my app.manifest file contains a ton ob errors:

[image]

All the red xml tags are marked as erroneous

- **assembly** => Element assembly must be declared
- **assemblyIdentity** => Cannot resolve assemblyIdentity
- **trustInfo** => uri is not registered

Moreover, when I try to access a file using streamWriter, I get an error `Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\xampp' is denied.` even though I requested administrator privileges in app.manifest (I never get UAC popup though).

What is going on here? Why is my app.manifest file bogus? Is there an easy way to create app.manifest in Rider, one that does not involve copy pasting app.manifest?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, the manifest file also has the compiler build action as 'Application Manifest' which tells that it needs to be embedded correctly when compiling.

I think in your configuration Rider may need to be told how to do that. Otherwise it will treat it as any other file, and not embed it properly in the exe you build.

Create a project in VS, and add a manifest file.

See the corresponding reference in the csproj file. You need to make your csproj the same in Rider. (I've never used to Rider so I'm not sure if there's a UI for it.)

For .NET Core

```
 <PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
<ApplicationManifest>app1.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

for .NET Framework

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned it's a validation bug.

Here is a [YouTrack bug from JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-39295) that was raised. The lines are marked red but app works just fine for me currently.